# Update multiple rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01427

Can you tell me how to update multiple rows in oracle as when I fired the update statement it gave me the following error

```
UPDATE  BI_BSELATEST_LATESTPRICESTEST
SET PREVIOUS_DAY_CLOSE =
    (SELECT  DISTINCT aa.DLYPRICE_CLOSE 
     FROM  DATAFEED_EQTY.FEED_DLYPRICE aa  ,
           (
           SELECT  a.sc_code ,  MAX(a.DLYPRICE_DATE) as max_date
           from    DATAFEED_EQTY.FEED_DLYPRICE a,BI_BSELATEST_LATESTPRICES b
           where   a.SC_CODE = b.SC_CODE
           and    a.ST_EXCHNG = 'BSE'
           and    a.DLYPRICE_DATE <   b.upd_time 
           group by a.sc_code
         ) bb
    WHERE  aa.SC_CODE =  bb.sc_code
    and    aa.DLYPRICE_DATE = max_date)
```

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Thanks in advance

Comment: None of the answers you've gotten on *any* questions before are good enough to accept (you accept answers by clicking the checkmark to the left)?

Comment: Thanks for posting some code. You can also format the code properly by indenting each line with 4 spaces (or highlight and click the "code" button on the toolbar)

Answer (score 2):

A subquery in your statement is wrong. You left off either a `WHERE` or `FIRST` clause, and now it's returning multiple values when it shouldn't.

You're basically trying to say `PREVIOUS_DAY_CLOSE` should be multiple values at the same time. I'm guessing you left off a `WHERE` clause on your subselect, which would link the results of that subquery to the particular row you're trying to update.  Something like (note the bolded line):

```
UPDATE  BI_BSELATEST_LATESTPRICESTEST
SET PREVIOUS_DAY_CLOSE =
    (SELECT  DISTINCT aa.DLYPRICE_CLOSE 
     FROM  DATAFEED_EQTY.FEED_DLYPRICE aa  ,
           (
           SELECT  a.sc_code ,  MAX(a.DLYPRICE_DATE) as max_date
           from    DATAFEED_EQTY.FEED_DLYPRICE a,BI_BSELATEST_LATESTPRICES b
           where   a.SC_CODE = b.SC_CODE
           and    a.ST_EXCHNG = 'BSE'
           and    a.DLYPRICE_DATE <   b.upd_time 
           group by a.sc_code
         ) bb
    WHERE  aa.SC_CODE =  bb.sc_code
    and    aa.DLYPRICE_DATE = max_date
```

```
   AND bb.sc_code = BI_BSELATEST_LATESTPRICESTEST.sc_code
```

```
    )
```

Although, I'll be honest, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do with this query.

Comment: m i want to update records in PREVIOUS_DAY_CLOSE field in BI_BSELATEST_LATESTPRICESTEST table with the values i get in select statement hope this info helps you..

Comment: @devang - Right, so for a certain given row of `BI_BSELATEST_LATESTPRICESTEST`, *which* value that you get from the select statement do you want. One column from one row can only have one value at any given time, right?

Comment: yes correct i get only when value for one column..but still it gives me the same error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: @devang - I don't think you're quite understanding. Take your subselect out and try running it by itself and see what result*s* you get, because you'll *surely* get more than one row.

Comment: @lc- i tried running the select and sub select query it gives me some 1000 rows now can u tell me how to update these rows in the PREVIOUS_DAY_CLOSE column in BI_BSELATEST_LATESTPRICESTEST table.

Comment: @lc- in oracle it does not allow multiple updates at a time as i tried updating by defining the value implicitly and it worked..

Comment: @devang - Ok I'm not sure how else to word it, but basically one column in *one row* in `BI_BSELATEST_LATESTPRICESTEST` **cannot contain 1000 values at the same time**. It's like saying I want x to equal 2, 3, and 4 at the same time.

So the question is: *As it goes through and updates each row, for a given existing row in `BI_BSELATEST_LATESTPRICESTEST`, which one of the 1000 rows do you want to set `PREVIOUS_DAY_CLOSE` to?*

Comment: @lc- i got what you saying i want to set the 1st highest value as my 
PREVIOUS_DAY_CLOSE value..

Comment: @lc- i even tried where exists clause but it also doesnt seem to work here..:(

Comment: @devang Then instead of `DISTINCT`, maybe you mean `MAX`? As in `(SELECT  MAX(aa.DLYPRICE_CLOSE)...`. But you still don't have any link between `aa`/`bb` and `BI_BSELATEST_LATESTPRICESTEST`, as I've suggested, so I'm afraid all rows are going to be replaced with the same max value...Could you post some example data and what you want to happen??

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this:

```
UPDATE  BI_BSELATEST_LATESTPRICESTEST b
SET PREVIOUS_DAY_CLOSE =
    (SELECT  DISTINCT aa.DLYPRICE_CLOSE 
     FROM  DATAFEED_EQTY.FEED_DLYPRICE aa  ,
           (
           SELECT  a.sc_code ,  MAX(a.DLYPRICE_DATE) as max_date
           from    DATAFEED_EQTY.FEED_DLYPRICE a
           where   a.SC_CODE = b.SC_CODE
           and    a.ST_EXCHNG = 'BSE'
           and    a.DLYPRICE_DATE <   b.upd_time 
           group by a.sc_code
         ) bb
    WHERE  aa.SC_CODE =  bb.sc_code
    and    aa.DLYPRICE_DATE = max_date)
```

This removes BI_BSELATEST_LATESTPRICESTEST from the sub-query and instead tells the database to use the columns from the table that it is updating to filter the sub-query.  As you had written it, the database had no way of knowing how to correlate the columns from the sub-query to the table being updated.